# Showing WinForms dialog with focus from powershell script

Tags: winforms, user-interface, powershell, focus

One of my coworkers just came to me with an interesting problem.

He's displaying a WinForms form from a PowerShell script, and while the form opens successfully it does not get focus. Instead the PowerShell command window retains focus until the form is explicitly clicked.

The script is being run from the PowerShell command line using .\ScriptName.ps1.

We've tried various combinations of dlg.ShowDialog() (with and without passing $this), dlg.Show(), dlg.Focus(), etc with no luck.

Does anybody know how to give the form focus when it's displayed?

Comment: Is it doing anything else beyond just calling Show()?  I imagine the command window just steals the focus back.  Try ShowDialog() for example.

Comment: That's what I expected the problem to be when he explained it to me, too, but he was in fact already using ShowDialog(). The issue turned out to be something deeper, but see my answer below for the solution he found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how we got it working (the first line is the one we were missing):

```
$WinForm.Add_Shown({$WinForm.Activate()})
$WinForm.ShowDialog($this) | out-null
```

Comment: Add_Shown is what I needed, but it doesn't seem to be documented in Powershell

Answer (score 0):

I was using C# in Powershell.
The `Add_Shown` bit in Redwood's answer translates to adding an event handler for `Shown`, or simply overriding `OnShown`:

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        this.Activate();
    }
```